# How to filter a MongoDB collection using information from another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections `Accounts` and `Debts`. I need to get the items in `Accounts` collection that have a "net savings" greater than a certain number. Net savings is the savings after all the debts are subtracted from the Account savings. Any pointers on how to solve this would be very helpful.

Accounts Collection:

```
{

  "AccountNumber": "A1234",
  "Savings": 1000
}
{

  "AccountNumber": "A4567",
  "Savings": 500
}
```

Debts Collection:

```
{

  "AccountNumber": "A1234",
  "Debt": 10,
  "Lender": "A"
}
{

  "AccountNumber": "A1234",
  "Debt": 20,
  "Lender": "B"
}
{

  "AccountNumber": "A4567",
  "Debt": 50,
  "Lender": "B"
}
```

Accounts with Net Savings > 500

```
{
  "AccountNumber": "A1234",
  "NetSavings": 970
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first find the account numbers from `Accounts` collection then use `$in` with `Debits` collection

```
const accountNumbers = (await Account.find({ Savings: { $gte: 500 }})).map(({ AccountNumber }) => AccountNumber)

const debits = await Debits.find({ AccountNumber: { $in: accountNumbers }})
```

Or using aggregate

```
Accounts.aggregte([
  { $lookup: {
    from: "debits",
    localField: "AccountNumber",
    foreignField: "AccountNumber",
    as: "acc"
  }},
  { $addFields: {
    NetSavings: {
      $subtract: ["$Savings", { $sum: "$acc.Debt" }]
    }
  }}
])
```